# How do I launch a website (with GET parameters) in the default browser in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, browser

How can I open a website in the user's default web browser (preferably platform-independent, but not required) using Ruby?

I've found several references to the Launchy gem, however Launchy doesn't seem to handle ampersands correctly.  For example, the command

```
Launchy.open("http://mysite.com?param1=a&param2=b")
```

causes the error "'param2' is not recognized as an internal or external command.  I'm using Windows and the Windows shell interprets an ampersand as a command separator, so I suspect that is causing the problem.  The Launchy documentation is very sparse: http://copiousfreetime.rubyforge.org/launchy/.

Others have suggested using the Windows start command, but that has the same problem.

Comment: No idea if this helps, but have you tried `Launchy.open("http://mysite.com?param1=a&amp;param2=b")`?

Comment: @mischa When using &amp; it responds with "amp is not recognizes as an internal or external command."  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try any other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's pretty old Launchy's [bug](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/5). It can be fixed adding `^` in the url before `&` char (as the guy who opened an issue suggests). I'll make a patch ASAP. So, right now you can use just plain `system` method for this job:

```
system("start http://google.com?a=1^&b2=2")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `Launchy::Browser.run("http://mysite.com?param1=a&param2=b")` ?